# How to edit the data in cells with different rows and columns respectively with userforms

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

Here is an example of how the data is placed:
[image]

Here is an example of how my userform is structured: [Client Userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1aaN.png)

The codes for the update button are as follows which does not work:

```
Private Sub UpdateCommandButton_Click()

    Dim countryname As String
    Dim username As String
    Dim CompanyName As String
    Dim onetime As String
    Dim actualmonthly As String

    'Updating based on User's Name as of now

    ActiveSheet.Activate

    countryname = countryTextBox.Text
    username = usernameComboBox.Text
    CompanyName = companyComboBox.Text
    onetime = oneTimeTextBox.Text
    actualmonthly = actualMonthlyTextBox.Text

    Cells(currentrow, 2).Value = countryname
    Cells(currentrow, 3).Value = username
    Cells(currentrow + 1, 4).Value = CompanyName
    Cells(currentrow + 1, 6).Value = onetime
    Cells(currentrow + 1, 7).Value = actualmonthly
    MsgBox "Client's Details Has Been Updated!"

End Sub
```

My userform will also display the respective data if the User is searched and the one time and monthly values will change respectively in the comboboxes

Thus, is it possible to edit the different cells respectively based on the inputs from the user form? (Examples of cells that I want to be able edited are `B19, C19, D20, D21, D22, E19, E20, E21, E22`)

Note that I do not want to hard code the cells which means that the userform can update other columns and rows if more data were to be added. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but your question is far too broad for this site.  Is there some *specific* part of this which is giving you problems?

Comment: @TimWilliams added the codes for my current update button which does not work, tried looking up on the internet but to no avail due to the data placement for this worksheet